# How can I mock a boto3 sns call in unit tests?

Tags: django, unit-testing, amazon-sns, boto3

I am trying to unit test a function:

```
@shared_task()
def push_notification(message=None, message_type=None, user_id=None, data={}):

    #  Get the aws arn from token table
    aws_token_data = AwsDeviceToken.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).latest("id")
    client = boto3.client('sns', **aws.AWS_CREDENTIAL)

    message = {
        'default': message,
         more stuff here 
         'data': data})
    }
    message = json.dumps(message, ensure_ascii=False)
    response = client.publish(
        TargetArn=str(aws_token_data.aws_PLATFORM_endpoint_arn),
        Message=message,
        MessageStructure='json',
        MessageAttributes={}
    )
    return response
```

When users register for our service they get a topic arn based on their device type.

I have tried:

```
def test_push_notification(self):
    with mock.patch('boto3.client') as mock_client:
        data = {'Some data': "to be sent"}
        push_notification(
            message="your invitation has been accepted",
            message_type='b2g_accepted',
            user=self.user,
            data=data
        )
        self.assertEqual(mock_client.call_count, 1)
```

Where self.user is a user registered in the setUp method of TestCase. This fails, the call_count is 0

I am scratching my head trying to figure out a way to test this function but mostly coming up with third party modules or examples for S3.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You need to mock where it is imported (unless it is a class method)

So if your push_notification function is in a module called my_module, you should write:

```
With mock.patch('my_module.boto3.client') as mock_client
```

Comment: How to mock the actual `publish` ?